# NSSegmentedControl as NSToolbarItems on Big Sur

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstoolbar, macos-big-sur, nssegmentedcontrol

When using `NSSegmentedControl` in toolbars (native `NSToolbar`) with templated `NSImage` instances the usability has significantly deteriorated on macOS Big Sur.

The selected item has an extremely low contrast in the new style used by macOS 11:

[image]

**Before** macOS 11 selected items were rendered in a high-contrast, inverted style -
the current selection was easily distinguished:

[image]

Any ideas on how to change this to make `NSSegmentedControl`s usable on Big Sur much appreciated.